# HTML Button Won't Right Align

Tags: html, css, button, alignment

I have the following HTML. I want the "Get Geotag" button to be right aligned and the text to be anywhere before/to the left of the button. However, currently I cannot figure out a way to get the buttons aligned properly and to continue functioning (the text for the input is based off of getLoc()). Any help would be appreciated!

```
          <button class="button button-positive button-clear pull-right" ng-click="getLoc()"  readonly>
                Get Geotag
            </button>
          <input type="text" value="{{geoString}}">
```

There is no related CSS.

I tried this: 
              
              
                    Get Geotag

which aligns correctly but then the location functionality goes away. I also tried to use things like float: right and right-align to no avail.

Comment: please provide your CSS code and what methods you tried that did not work

Comment: I also tried placing the <input> line above the <button></button> but that does not seem to be appearing above. @Aziz

Answer (score 1):

```
 <div class="center">
<button class="button button-positive button-clear pull-right" ng-click="getLoc()"  readonly>
            Get Geotag
        </button>
      <input type="text" value="{{geoString}}"></div>
```

Two Options:
1. 
    .center{display:inline-block;}
2.
    .center{display:flex;
    flex-direction:row;
    justify-content:space-around; /* you could also use justify-content:space-between; *\
}

My code had a typing mistake. Fixed it

Comment: Any way to get them on the same line?

Comment: Isn't this doing that?

Comment: Put them in a div and assign the class "center", then use this css .center{display:flex; flex-direction:row; justify-content:space-around; /* you could also use justify-content:space-between; *\ }

Comment: No, unfortunately not. Although they are better, the Get Geotag button is above the input. Ideally, I'd like them both to be on the same row.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to say without your css. But I'm trying to help you. 
**CSS:**

```
.my_css{display:inline-block}
```

**HTML:**

```
<button class="button button-positive button-clear pull-right my_css" ng-click="getLoc()"  readonly>
    Get Geotag
</button>
<input type="text" value="{{geoString}}">
```

Comment: I don't have any CSS (empty file). Right now the way it looks is like: 
Get Geotag   (lat, long)